# Constructor similar to std::map or std::vector in a class

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, std

I'm creating a class and I want to know how to create a constructor similar to the `std::map` or `std::vector` style.

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> map = {
    {"foo", "bar"},
    {"biz", "buz"},
    {"bez", "boz"}
};
```

The difference is that I don't want my class to ask for types that wants to accept, just like `std::map` does.

```
std::map<std::string, std::string>
```

I want my class to accept that style of arguments:

```
{
    {"foo", "bar"},
    {"biz", "buz"},
    {"bez", "boz"}
};
```

But with defined type. (std::string, Typer)

The 'Typer' is a class that I will insert as value on the `std::map`.

Comment: You can't deduce initializer lists.

Comment: The simple answer is: use the map as the second parameter, as follows: const std::map<std::string, std::string>& data. In this case you can use your syntax for the second parameter. This is not a duplicate question, by the way. You needn't use an initializer list here. This works both in VS2013 and GCC 4.8.1.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a constructor taking `std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::string, Typer>>`, like this:

```
struct Typer
{
  std::string data;

  Typer(const char *s) : data(s) {}
};


struct MyClass
{
  MyClass(std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::string, Typer>> i)
    : myMap(begin(i), end(i))
  {}

  std::map<std::string, Typer> myMap;
};

int main()
{
  MyClass m = {
    {"foo", "bar"},
    {"biz", "buz"},
    {"bez", "boz"}
  };
}
```

[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/SeEmVl)

Answer (score 3):

`typedef std::map<std::string, Typer> MyType;`